# Change color of a column in highchart with a default color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have to change the color of one of the columns in highcharts. I see what we can change it for the entire series but haven't been able to figure out changing it for only 1 column. This is how the my series is made:

```
var dates = [];
var scores = [];
vm.data.values.forEach(function (item) {
    dates.push(datefilter(item.date, 'yyyy-MM'));

    if (item.isCurrent) {
        scores.push({
            y: item.score || 0,
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                lineWidth: 5,
                lineColor: "#FF0000"
                }
            });
    }
    else {
        scores.push(item.score || 0);
    }
});

vm.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer'
                        },
                        marker: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            symbol: 'circle'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Scores"
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: dates
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Scores',
                    data: scores,
                    color: "#249858"
                }
            ]
        };
    };
```

The html of the component looks like below:

```
<highchart config="vm.chartConfig"></highchart>
```

With this code, I have only been able to see only 1 color that I got set in the chartConfig object. The one that I set while creating my series data in the foreach loop never takes effect. Any pointers or plunkr link would be really great.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar problems, the color I was setting was in wrong places. Changing

**OLD**

```
if (item.isCurrent) {
    scores.push({
        y: item.score || 0,
        marker: {
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: "#FF0000"
            }
        });
}
else {
    scores.push(item.score || 0);
}
```

with 
**NEW CODE**

```
if (item.isCurrent) {
    scores.push({
        y: item.score || 0,
        marker: {
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: "#FF0000"
            }, 
        color: '#FF0000'
        });
}
else {
    scores.push(item.score || 0);
}
```

did the trick for me.

**NOTE:** The marker color I am keeping is because I am rendering line and column charts. And color works for column while marker works for line chart.